Im writing a custom logger with Morgan causing emfile error in ec2 why?
I am using Morgan for logging in my Node.js application and trying to log each user's activity into separate log files. Here is my current setup:
const logStreams: { [key: string]: fs.WriteStream } = {};

// Adding Logs
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use((req: any, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    try {
      const decode = jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`) as JwtPayload;
      req.user = { id: decode?.userId };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      req.user = { id: 'default' };
    }
  } else {
    req.user = { id: 'default' };
  }
  next();
});
function getLogStream(filePath: string) {
  if (!logStreams[filePath]) {
    logStreams[filePath] = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, { flags: 'a' });
    logStreams[filePath].on('finish', () => {
      console.log(`Stream for ${filePath} has been closed.`);
      delete logStreams[filePath];
    });
  }
  return logStreams[filePath];
}

app.use((req: any, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.user.id;
  const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  const logDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../logs', userId);

  fsExtra.ensureDirSync(logDir);

  const logFilePath = path.join(logDir, `${date}.log`);
  const accessLogStream = getLogStream(logFilePath);
  morgan(':date :method :url :status :res[content-length]  - :response-time ms ', {
    stream: accessLogStream,
  })(req, res, next);
});

morgan.token('date', (req: any) => {
  return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
});

morgan.token('user-id', (req: { user: { id: any } }, res: any) => req.user.id);

I tried hashing the log stream to prevent opening multiple streams, but I am still getting the EMFILE error. I am new to Node.js and having a hard time understanding how to fix this issue.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated
